# How to make an inverse transparent circle in CSS

Tags: css, transparent

how do i make a section on color background transparent with css?
here is example for this background

[image]

i still didn't try anything becouse i have no idea how to do that so please help me.
if im putting its as div on div and typing in the css:

```
.Xclass{ background: transparent; }
```

its still show me the white background.

please help me guys.

Comment: Could you paste some more code? HTML-structure as well as parent div's CSS would help.

Comment: where is your section? I couldn't find any Xclass class in the html.

Comment: Try giving `.Xclass` a background that matches the main background. Otherwise you could always look into CSS Masking: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-masking/

Comment: `background: transparent` can't influence the parent container's background. You could create a background-image with a transparent circle in it.

Answer (score 5):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/nugog/1/edit)**

- Place an `overflow:hidden` **square** with **no background**.
- Inside that square - put a **circle** with a high `box-shadow` **spread radius**

```css
#image{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/gVcxX9C.png);
  height:500px;
  width:600px;
}
#box{
  position:absolute;
  left:300px;
  top:200px;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  overflow:hidden; /* to contain #circle's box-shadow */
}
#circle{
  position:relative;
  margin:30px auto;
  width: 150px;
  height:150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px #fff; /* !!! */
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="image">
    <div id="box"><div id="circle"></div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not that it matters but you could use a pseudo-element instead of the '#circle' div for slightly less HTML. +1

Comment: That is amazing! Can you explain why that works? Why does `overflow: hidden` cause any `box-shadow` properties to be clipped?

Comment: @LukeKnepper exactly. The box shadow of the inner circle will be clipped by the overflow:hidden parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.Xclass {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

or

```
.Xclass {
 background-color: rgba(15,15,15,0.7);
}
```